# Port 80 traffic is not redirected?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I have tried editing with my /etc/httpd/conf.d/website.conf file with the below and also the /var/www/website/.htaccess with the below.

```
> -<VirtualHost *:80>
> -ServerName website.co.uk
> -ServerAlias *.website.co.uk
> -DocumentRoot /var/www/website.co.uk
> -RewriteEngine on
> -RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website\.co\.uk [NC]
> -RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> -RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
> -</VirtualHost>
```

> 

```
> -<VirtualHost *:443>
> -ServerName website.co.uk
> -ServerAlias *.website.co.uk
> -DocumentRoot /var/www/website.co.uk
> -SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.co.uk/fullchain.pem
> -SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.co.uk/privkey.pem
> -Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
> -</VirtualHost>
```

still traffic is not redirected for SSL, any idea? Should I change the setting in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf